# Flask - rendering temporary/secret pages

Tags: html, flask

What is the best way to render (I know only of render_template) and serve a html-page (from a string or from an actual html-file) without disclosing the path of any of the content of e.g. images on the page? When I inspect the page, I can see the full path all the way down to the name of the static-folder.

I presently can do it by putting explicit links to in the html-file using dedicated flask-image-serving flask-methods just to hide user_id and directories. (one reason for this is that a doc on the web page may want to be shared anonymously). But then I am sending a complete html-file with send_from_directory; it is not rendered by Flask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're concerned about exposing the full path of the static assets (like images) in your HTML source code, you can consider using data URIs to embed the images directly within the HTML. Data URIs encode the image data directly into the URL, removing the need to reference an external image file. However, please be aware that this approach might lead to larger HTML file sizes due to the encoded image data.

Here's how you could use data URIs to embed images in your HTML:

```
import base64
from flask import Flask, make_response, render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)

def embed_image_as_data_uri(image_path):
    with open(image_path, "rb") as image_file:
        image_data = image_file.read()
        image_base64 = base64.b64encode(image_data).decode("utf-8")
        image_mime_type = "image/jpeg"  # Adjust this based on your image type
        data_uri = f"data:{image_mime_type};base64,{image_base64}"
        return data_uri

@app.route('/')
def index():
    # Generate HTML content with embedded image using a data URI
    image_data_uri = embed_image_as_data_uri("static/images/your_image.jpg")
    html_content = f"""
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('serve_static', filename='styles/main.css') }}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="{image_data_uri}" alt="Image">
        <h1>Welcome to My Page</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
    """
    
    response = make_response(html_content)
    response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/html"
    return response

# ... (rest of your code)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

> Note: This might not be the best way, but this can achieve what you want here. Also, passing parameters from the frontend to the backend using the above-rendered way can lead to an XSS attack.

Comment: Thanks. It's such a mess. There is send_file_from_directory. I just would assume there could be a render_template_from_directory as well, when the stem of the files is set temporarily for a particular temporary routing/viewing given some state (such as user xyz browsing, and not user abc).